# How to trim an SSN that generates from a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an SSN thats being sent in via a model that needs to be trimmed to only show the last four.

I have it written as so

```
string primarySsn = primaryApplicant.Ssn;
Console.WriteLine(primarySsn.Remove(0, 5));
```

This isn't trimming and is still leaving the XXX-XX- that I don't want on the string.

Comment: Your code works almost fine. Try this https://dotnetfiddle.net/BM1mWt

Comment: Keep in mind that the `Remove` method _does not_ alter the original string.  So in your example, `primarySsn` will remain unchanged after the call to Remove.  The code you provided should display only the last 4 characters of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
var lastFour = primarySsn.Substring(primarySsn.Length-4,4);
```